# How to enable a smartphone sized Android application on larger screens

Tags: android-layout, android

My problem can be summed up in one picture which can be see in this location:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaDEw.jpg

The application had originally been developed for smartphone, and on a small resolution there is no problem, the application fills the whole screen. But in tablet, as you can see, only the size corresponding to a smartphone is used.

I guess that this means that somewhere the height and width values are hard set. But I cannot see where! Where is it possible to set height and width for all the application (all activities are doing the same thing).

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dombox.app"
android:versionCode="11"
android:versionName="2.0.4" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DomboxHome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.list.ZonesList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Dombox.MENU" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.list.EquipementsList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PullToRefreshActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:label="Tests for Android Dombox"
        android:targetPackage="com.application.androiddombox" >
    </instrumentation>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.list.SuiviConsoList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.list.PlanningList"       android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
</application>
```

And here is one of mine layout (there are all in the folder /res/layout/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<fragment
    android:name="com.dombox.app.fragment.MenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="30">
    <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/list_text -->
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:name="com.dombox.app.fragment.SettingsFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="70">
    <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/settings -->
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your app is running in compatibility mode, Put this piece of code just before the `<application>` tag in your manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Hope that works,

Comment: Thank you very  much that was the missing part. but the parameter android:xlargeScreens seam to not been supported in Android 2.1, I'm i right ? For the one who are looking where to put the support screen TAG : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Works perfectly. But just to avoid other people doubting as me. This tag needs to be just before the `<application` tag of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: @OscarPérez feel free to upvote a question / answer you think is good and can help others or has helped you..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `android:weightSum="100"` to your **LinearLayout**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml. This tells the system that your app is compatible with xlarge screens (tablets), and that your app should be stretch to fill screen.

Comment: That you for your answer. You where right I was missing the supports-screens tag. but the parameter android:xlargeScreens seam to not been supported on Android-2.1 Have got this error : "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'". Anyway I put <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/> And it's working !

Comment: Great :) Forgot android:xlargeScreens is only supported in API 9+,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are obviously missing one of the important stuff.

There is no [supports-screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) tag in your manifest file, so by default "normalScreens" is set to true and all others false.

[Here is the link for more info on Supporting Multiple Resolution.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Also check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the missing part !